# Turbo Boost Technology Monitor is EOL so what can I use to monitor Turbo Boost on my CPU?

Tags: windows, cpu, monitoring, turbo-boost

Turbo Boost Technology Monitor is EOL, and quite honestly I can't tell if it works anymore or not with Windows 8.1. Regardless, soon it will be removed since its end of life is soon upon us. What can I use to monitor Turbo Boost on my CPU instead of it?

Edit: I've tried CPU-Z. It doesn't work with monitoring the highest active core's turbo mode because it averages out all of the cores at once. I'm also looking for a free solution, like how Turbo Boost Technology Monitor is free.

Comment: It would help if you explained what "Turbo Boost Technology Monitor" was and what it did. Or, better yet, what exactly you are trying to do. Also, what does this have to do with multiple monitors?

Comment: I thought the name of the utility was pretty self-explanatory. Turbo Boost Technology Monitor is a Windows application from Intel that monitors and displays the clock speed of your CPU even while it is in turbo mode: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=19105 I wasn't able to get turbo data from, say, CPU-Z, and the last line of my question states, "What can I use to monitor Turbo Boost on my CPU instead of it?" which is what I am trying to do. Meant to tag as monitoring. Thanks.

Comment: @Madball73 That question is way too specific to a particular processor. Surely you have enough intelligence to see that...this is probably why Googling this issue never turned up anything useful up for me.

Comment: It's not though.  Have you reviewed the software referenced there?

Comment: Not yet. The link is quite helpful though, I'll give you that. Argus may work, but sadly, it costs money. From your link, I can also see why CPU-Z doesn't work. CPU-Z averages out all the cores, including the inactive ones. I honestly think it would be easier for me to write my own core tracking application at this point than to pay for Argus. Besides, it has an ugly UI. It looks like an old MFC application trying to pretend its a WPF app.

Comment: Please modify your question to include the fact that CPU-Z has been tried and does not correctly display turbo boost status, and that you are looking for a free solution.

Comment: Sensible enough, alright. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, just posting back with some updates:

1. Hyper-V was stopping turbo boost from happening on my machine, so that's one big problem that I was facing and the reason why Turbo Boost Technology Monitor wasn't working. If you guys are seeing the same thing, open up Control Panel -> Uninstall a program -> Turn windows features on or off, and turn off Hyper-V.
2. [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) is a great piece of software that I came across. It can monitor core speeds, and the best part is that its free and much better than Turbo Boost Technology Monitor.